# Convert urls to links unless they are in BBCode with PHP

Tags: php, regex, bbcode

I have text that supports BBCode and I use a custom PHP function to do the replacing instead of using PECL package or anything. It's working great to turn:

```
[url=http://www.google.com]Google[/url]
```

to

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

I also have a custom BBCode tag that turns the tag into an iframe:

```
[customtag]abc[/customtag]
```

to

```
<iframe src="http://example.com/abc"></iframe>
```

But now I have a requirement to change urls that are just typed normally to turn them into links. So if you type:

```
http://www.google.com
```

it will turn it into:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

I've used this regex to do this:

```
$string = preg_replace('@(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)@', '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$1</a>', $string);
```

But it's also matching what is in bbcode. If I include it after I parse the bbcode then it changes things in the anchor. Also happens for images and the iframe.

So how I can I change plain urls but ignore ones that are within a bbcode tag or already in a html tag?

Comment: Best way would be to fix the *"custom PHP function"* so that it handles plain URLs as well (or use something that does all this for you already). That way you don't have to parse the input/generated output several times.

Comment: Yes, that's obviously the end goal.

Comment: Are you asking for how to do that? In that case you are not providing enough information. We'd have to see what that "custom PHP function" looks like if you want any help with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the "best" solution, but you can use a negative lookbehind (`(?<!...)`) to make sure that the URL isn't prefixed by `'`, `"`, or `=`.  The obvious limitations are if someone writes something like:

> Let's visit "https://google.com" on our computers.  Or the link=https://google.com.

Anyways, the negative lookbehind would go at the very beginning of your expression and contain a character class: `["'=]`.

```
(?<!["'=])(https?://([-\w\.]+[-\w])+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_\.#-]*(\?\S+)?[^\.\s])?)?)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dY2eQ6)

Comment: This method worked perfect. I added > to the lookbehind, other than that worked great. Thank you

Comment: +1, but would suggest telling Mitchell about the unneeded characters in the char classes, for instance escaping the periods with `\.`, or `_` when we already have `\w`, and perhaps about the unneeded capture groups.